# Struggling to get swing on mouseover not onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get this div to swing on mouseover only and not on page load. Here is the JS:

```
(function swing() {
var ang  = 20,
    dAng = 10,
    ddAng = .5,
    dir  = 1,
    box = document.getElementById("box");

(function setAng(ang){
    box.style.WebkitTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';
    box.style.MozTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';
    dir = -dir;
    if (dAng > 1)
        dAng -= ddAng;

    if (Math.abs(ang) > 0)
        setTimeout(setAng, 1000, dir * (Math.abs(ang)-dAng));
})(ang);

box.mouseover = function(){
    box.style.WebkitTransform =  'rotate(-20deg)';
    box.style.MozTransform =  'rotate(-20deg)';
    setTimeout(swing, 1000);
}
})();
```

As you can see, it is swinging on load. just not mouseover.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qqsLW/

Cheers guys

Comment: mouseover change to onmouseover

Comment: Try *reading* the helpful tag pop-ups before slapping them on your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this works for me

```
(function swing() {
var ang  = 20,
    dAng = 10,
    ddAng = .5,
    dir  = 1,
    box = document.getElementById("box");

function setAng(ang){
    box.style.WebkitTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';
    box.style.MozTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';
    dir = -dir;
    if (dAng > 1)
        dAng -= ddAng;

    if (Math.abs(ang) > 0)
        setTimeout(setAng, 1000, dir * (Math.abs(ang)-dAng));
};

box.onmouseover = function(){
    console.log('over');
    box.style.WebkitTransform =  'rotate(-20deg)';
    box.style.MozTransform =  'rotate(-20deg)';
    setTimeout(function(){
        setAng(ang)
    }, 1000);
}
```

})();

Comment: @ukasz-szewczak - I have now added it to my site and I get this error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmouseover' of null  - Any ideas?

Comment: it looks like your code does not found container with the "box" id

Comment: @ukasz-szewczak it is definitely there. :'(

Comment: put console.log(box) after box variable definition, and show what it is

Comment: You put your script on page before or after the box container?

Answer (score 0):

Take the mouseover assignment out of the `swing` function.

If you also want to prevent it from executing immediately, don't run `swing`, i.e. remove the `()` after its definition.